# Proving that the difference of the terms of a sequence, multiplied by $n$ converge

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove some theorem, and in the proof of it I have to check the fact that if the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(a_n - a_{n-1}) = 0. $$ I think that this is true because I have tried with many different sequences and it holds, but I do not know how to prove it.

If this is not true, what is a counterexample for it?

Comment: For $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ to converge, where $a_n$ is a positive monotonically decreasing sequence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$.  I think you can get quite a bit out of that?

Comment: You may need to restrict this to positive sequences for it to hold.

Comment: Counterexample with positive terms: $a_n=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Answer (score 6):

The sequence $\{a_n\}:=\{(-1)^n/n\}$ converges to zero. However

$$n\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n-1}\right)=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac n{n-1}\right)=(-1)^n\left(2+\frac 1{n-1}\right)$$

does not converge.

Comment: It should be $(2 + 1/(n-1))$ at the end.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for the correction @jiyanez